# How to get the position according to the element in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using `ExpandableListView` by the reference of [this](https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/ExpandableListView). By using this I'm getting the position according to the `OnItemClickListener` but I want to get the particular position without clicking any element.

For example: I want to get the "Title Item 20" position. How to get the position of that particular element?

**Edit:** We know "Title Item 20" is in the expandable list view. So, i want to use the variable of "Title Item 20" and get the position according to the "Title Item 20" variable

Answer (score 0):

You can write a clickListener in getGroupView method for the View.I think this is the easiest way to get the position. You can get the position from the parameter.

Comment: Hi Zahidul Islam, when we use clickListener, we will get the position according to the our click. Can you elaborate it according to your answer?

Comment: // overwrite the function 
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null,true);

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Your position : "+groupPosition); // This is the title position 
            }
        });

return view;
}

Comment: Hi thank you for your interest. Previously also i am getting the position according to the expansion but i don't need that. For more explanation please see the edited version of the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code inside OnItemClickListener.It hopefully works...

```
 String value = lvItems.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position : " +value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hi Naveen thank you for your response. We will get the position according to this but i want to get the position according to the value For example: We know "Title Item 20" is in the expandable list view. So, i want to use the variable "Title Item 20" and get the position according to ""Title Item 20"" variable